# how to stop php countdown timer at zero

Tags: php, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I want to stop my php countdown timer to stop at 00:00:00:00

here is my code

```
$due_date = strtotime('July 4, 2014 10:33 PM');
$rem = $due_date - time();
$day = floor($rem / 86400);
$hr  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
$min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
$sec = ($rem % 60);
echo "$day Days $hr Hours $min Minutes $sec Seconds Remaining...";
```

but it runs further to -1 and so on in minus values.

i dont want it, I want to stop it at zeros. So I can echo my any msg when it stops at zero.
any idea how to do it?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. Is this running in a loop as a 'real' countdown timer or is it only updating the countdown on a page load... or.... ?

$rem can be checked for a negative value. If negative or zero, you have your notice that the timer should be all zeros.

Comment: its not updating on page load.

Comment: so how is it being updated? Are you running php in a loop or ... ?

Comment: this is the all code it isn't in any loop

Comment: so you are loading some file, foo.php, which runs only this code and one-time only echoes your '$day...' line... which just sits there until you reload the file, yes?

Comment: What do you mean not any file. How are you executing this code?

Comment: yes this is in a php file but not from any other php file like through include, or include_once or require etc

Comment: that's what I meant. So there isn't a ticking countdown timer on a page, it needs a page reload to get a new value. I've put my answer in below, see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$due_date = strtotime('July 4, 2014 00:33 PM');

if($due_date > time()) {
    $rem = $due_date - time();
    $day = floor($rem / 86400);
    $hr  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
    $min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
    $sec = ($rem % 60);
    echo "$day Days $hr Hours $min Minutes $sec Seconds Remaining..."; // Timer still has time to go.
} else {
    echo "0 Days 0 Hours 0 Minutes 0 Seconds Remaining..."; // Timer is finished, now at 00:00:00
}
```

Comment: will this freeze on zeros? I want to just stop all values of timer at zeros

Comment: Let me check few more tests.

Comment: Sure, I never forget to check any answer as accepted.

Comment: Now how can I echo any thing when timer outs ?

Comment: Is this question is closed?

Comment: I mean when timer goes to zero i want to echo another thing

Comment: Just change `echo "0 Days 0 Hours 0 Minutes 0 Seconds Remaining...";` to whatever you want.

Comment: not just this, I want also this but echo something expire somewhere else

Comment: `if($due_date <= time()) { echo "expired"; }` Something like that can be used to tell if its expired.

Comment: OK let me check it now.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$rem = $due_date - time();
```

will be zero or negative if past the due date. So add something like:

```
if($rem <= 0) {
    //do your echo here for 00:00:00
}
else {
    // do your countdown math as normal
}
```